# dconf-editor loses settings

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, dconf

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a new ASUS laptop, and dconf-editor does not keep the changes that I make in executable-text-activation (in /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences). I think that this is a general problem since the warning message upon entry to dconf-editor cannot be removed.

Thanks for your help and best wishes, John

Comment: I just installed classic GNOME (Flashback-Metacity), and the problems with dconf-editor have gone away [although I get a message saying "** (dconf-editor:2940): WARNING **: 20:09:38.678: source-manager.vala:98: Schema with id “org.gnome.gnome-flashback.input-sources” contains neither keys nor children." I am not saying the question has been solved since dconf-editor should also work in the normal default GNOME.

Comment: Hello you! Have you found a solution since there? Could you register it through an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It has been nearly a year and my Ubuntu has been updated regularly in the meantime and is now 18.04.04. My executable-text-activation as set back then in dconf-editor is still working fine under classic GNOME (Flashback-Metacity) or under default Ubuntu GNOME.

I have done some testing and now conclude that the executable-text-activation parameter in dconf-editor seems to work the same under either classic GNOME (Flashback-Metacity) or under default Ubuntu GNOME. The default value is always "display". When one sets dconf-editor to use a customized value (and then either clicks on the check-mark or changes screen within dconf-editor), that is kept in the dconf-editor configuration (even when exiting and reloading dconf-editor) but the change is not applied until Ubuntu is rebooted (changing session does not seem to do it).

I still get the same warning each time that I load dconf-editor, and I am sometimes (but not always) also getting seemingly innocuous system software problem warnings when using dconf-editor (but as my system is a little bit kinky after recent partition restoration, this may not generally apply).